# Regex compare two strings

Tags: google-sheets, worksheet-function, regex

I have two strings

```
"*j?a?c?k*c?o?o?p?e?r*a?v?o?n*l?a?k?e*o?h*"
```

and

```
"*j?a?c?k*c?o?o?p?e?r*t?r?a?n?s?p?o?r?t*a?v?o?n*l?a?k?e*t?e?r?m?i?n?a?l*"
```

These seem like they should be equal in regex. However, I cannot find a function in Google sheets (`vlookup`, `search`, ...) that provides this answer because neither is a substring of the other.

Is there anyway to equate them?

Answer (score 1):

Use [REGEXMATCH](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098292)

> Whether a piece of text matches a regular expression.
>
> **Sample Usage**
> `REGEXMATCH("Spreadsheets", "S.r")`
>
> **Syntax**
>
> ```
> REGEXMATCH(text, regular_expression)
> ```
>
> - text - The text to be tested against the regular expression.
> - regular_expression - The regular expression to test the text against.